# Can't call class instance variable within a method

Tags: python, oop

I am somewhat experienced with python, but terrible with OOP. I'd say I'm at the line between beginner and intermediate, if that helps.

I have a class:

```
class WikiScrape:
    def __init__(self, pages=[]):
        self.pages = set() #my instance variable
```

Here's the method in question

```
def get_links(self, URL):
    pages = self.pages
    html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/%s" % URL)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)

    for link in bsObj.findAll('a', href=re.compile(r'^/wiki')):
        if 'href' in link.attrs:
            if link.attrs['href'] not in pages:
                # new page found
                new_page = link.attrs['href']
                print(new_page)
                pages.add(new_page)
                self.get_links(new_page)
```

What This does is check if something within the list of links is in the set called pages. My confusion comes from referencing this variable within the get_links() method.

referencing the variable like:

```
if link.attrs['href'] not in self.pages:
```

gave me a name error. It was my understanding that instance variables can be called with self as long as they are defined in the class instance. Confused, I tried many things.

I added the line:

```
pages = self.pages
```

in the function and it worked.

Basically, setting a variable to self.pages as opposed to referencing self.pages in the for loop made the function run just fine.

My question is, why did I have to do this? Why couldn't I just reference self.pages without setting it to a variable within the method in question. Is it even something to worry about? Something with scopes?

Thanks for reading and if something isn't clear, I'll be happy to clarify

Comment: You probably had a typo in your first version. there's no reason that `in self.pages` shouldn't work.

Comment: I'm assuming you're aware of the issues around mutable default arguments..?  (not that it would be related to a name error)

Comment: I'm not actually. Is the default parameter causing me issues?(I am getting NameError)

Answer (score 0):

I think self.pages should be OK.

But I think there are some strange points in your code:

the last line in the function of get_links, you write
    self.get_links(new_page)

It seems not reasonable for me, if my understanding is right, what you want is trying to traverse all the nodes in a graph.

But you use self.get_links(), that means every time you use the same node to find the links, right?

So following is the purposed sample code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.link_hash = {}
        self.is_seen = False

def depth_first_search(node):
     '''
     you can check the search algorithm
     '''
```

The search algorithm can help you traverse all the nodes.

Hope this will help for you.